# Getting AsyncStorage data on back navigation in react native

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage, stack-navigator

I have a home screen which pulls some data from `AsyncStorage` in `componentDidMount()`. I'm using `StackNavigator` to move from my home screen to another screen to add some data to `AsyncStorage` which should also be shown on the home screen. Thanks to `StackNavigator` I have a back arrow on that second screen which allows navigation back to my home screen. My home screen `componentDidMount()` does not get invoked on that back navigation so my home screen does not get updated with the new data I added.

I don't know where to pull from `AsyncStorage` in my home screen now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't related to `AsyncStorage`, what is happening is that `react-navigation` only mounts screens once (thus triggering your `componentDidMount`) per mounted navigator.

I'm assuming when you load data from `AsyncStorage` you save it to the component inner state, to redux store, or use it as params of a subcomponent. Something react-like. So you can pass a callback to the second screen that changes this inner state with [setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate), thus triggering a rerender, or you could save the new data in redux and connect the store and your home screen.

Comment: The callback worked. I wanted to get this working without Redux/Thunk. Thanks a lot!